# How do i upload tinkergraph into python/gremlin?

Tags: python, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlinpython

I am trying to use gremlin in python. I imported the following:

```
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import *
import asyncio
statics.load_statics(globals())
```

When i run this:

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open() 
graph.io(graphml()).readGraph('air-routes.graphml')
```

i get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'TinkerGraph' is not defined
```

How do i resolve this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58026770/1497139

Answer (score 2):

There is no TinkerGraph in Python. In gremlin-python you only get a reference to a graph remotely on a server and that might be a TinkerGraph or something else. If you want to load data that way, you must issue that command as a script through a `Client` instance:

```
client = Client('ws://localhost:45940/gremlin', 'g')
client.submit("graph.io(graphml()).readGraph('air-routes.graphml');[]").all().result()
```

where "graph" in that script is a `Graph` instance that already exists on the server (and is likely empty). If you're using Gremlin Server, you might consider doing that loading separately as part of [Gremlin Server startup](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#starting-gremlin-server) as well and then just using gremlin-python to query that data. That would probably be best in this example as the data would just be present when the server is started.

Note that in 3.4.0, we introduce the `io()` step which will be part of gremlin-python directly at which point you will be able to directly do:

```
g.io('air-routes.xml').read()
```

in native python and it will just work (again, the `Graph` instance must be defined remotely) though the file must be readable by the server.

Here's my working example in the Python shell for submitting a script, first with the tornado error and then without:

```
$ env/bin/python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gremlin_python.driver.client import Client
>>> client = Client('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g')
>>> client.submit("g.V()").all().result()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smallette/git/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/gremlin-python/target/python3/gremlin_python/driver/client.py", line 51, in __init__
    from gremlin_python.driver.tornado.transport import (
  File "/home/smallette/git/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/gremlin-python/target/python3/gremlin_python/driver/tornado/transport.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tornado import ioloop, websocket
ImportError: No module named 'tornado'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/smallette/git/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/gremlin-python/target/python3/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py", line 45, in __init__
    password=password)
  File "/home/smallette/git/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/gremlin-python/target/python3/gremlin_python/driver/client.py", line 54, in __init__
    raise Exception("Please install Tornado or pass"
Exception: Please install Tornado or passcustom transport factory
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
>>> exit()
$ env/bin/pip install tornado
Collecting tornado
Collecting backports-abc>=0.4 (from tornado)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/56/6f3ac1b816d0cd8994e83d0c4e55bc64567532f7dc543378bd87f81cebc7/backports_abc-0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: backports-abc, tornado
Successfully installed backports-abc-0.5 tornado-5.1.1
smallette@ubuntu:~/git/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/gremlin-python/target/python3$ env/bin/python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gremlin_python import statics
>>> client = Client('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g')
>>> client.submit("g.V()").all().result()
[v[0]]
```

Comment: when i run client = Client('ws://localhost:45940/gremlin', 'g') it says it needs 'Exception: Please install Tornado or passcustom transport factory'. i then did from gremlin_python.driver.tornado.transport import (
                    TornadoTransport) - but then i get the error: ImportError: cannot import name 'TracebackFuture'

Comment: i guess you need to install https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures

Comment: if by this you mean  'import concurrent.futures' then i already have it.. i still get same error. i already have tornado installed it's when i use this statment:'import tornado.web' i get an error.

Comment: can you please see my updated answer. perhaps give this simply try in your python shell and see if it works. note that i get the error you initially had with tornado, resolve it by installing tornado with pip and then it's good to go. perhaps you still have a dependency issue somewhere?

Comment: tahnk you i will check this

Comment: I came accross this over a year ago and already thought it is a very bad idea to have no proper python reachable API for this. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2294 - I am downvoting since the answer is avoiding an improvement.